# Is there a way to make Firefox and Chrome scroll the same element?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to get a reference to the physical location of my canvas element in relation to the document (not the viewport). My problem is that in Chrome `document.body.scrollTop` returns the correct scroll position and in FireFox `document.documentElement.scrollTop` returns the correct position. Obviously Firefox just uses a different element to calculate scroll position, but this is really a pain.

This seems like it would be a common issue. Does anyone know if there's a way to force compatibility with a CSS rule? Like, force scrolling to happen on the body or on the html element? I've tried setting the `overflow` property various ways on each, but it doesn't seem to do it.

I'm open to JavaScript solutions, but I'm trying to avoid "if firefox use this value, else if chrome use this one." CSS would be so much nicer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
```

In Chrome the first expression always returns `0` then the second part is adopted.

In Firefox if, however, the first expression returns `0` (page at the top), the second expression returns `0` as well.

This solution also works in other major browsers.

Comment: As of today, `document.documentElement.scrollTop` returns actual scrollTop on Chrome.